# Create a URL from of a string (named route)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an action called `home`.
I store `"home_url"` in the database.

I need to generate the full URL form this string.

For example,

Input: `"home_url"`

Desired output: `"http://myhostname/home/index.html"`

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
self.send("home_url")
```

For example

```
<%= link_to "Home", self.send("home_url") %>
```

And obviously `home_url` should be presented in your `routes.rb` file